# Delete 'border-right' from last list item

Tags: jquery, html, css

Friends,

This is the case:

```
<div class="navigation-sub">
    <ul class="subnavlist">
        <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the CSS, where every list item has a right border:

```
.navigation-sub li a { border-right:1px solid #FFF; }
```

Next, we want to delete the right border of 'item 4' - the last item in the UL, with:

```
.subnavlist li:last-child { border-right:0px; }
```

I tried several tricks, but nothing is happening so far and I don't know where to go from here.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are giving the `<a>`s a border, and removing it from the last `<li>`. Try this instead:

```
.subnavlist li:last-child a { border-right: none; }
```

Comment: will affect all `<a> tags

Comment: Many thanks to all! All answers are working depending on the use of them. Sorry, for the blindness on my part here :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
     $(".subnavlist li").last().find("a").css("borderRight",0);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are applying border to `<a>` tag, but trying to reset the `li`

```
.subnavlist li:last-child a{border-right:none}
```